# Mysql Timeclock status and hours updates

Tags: php, mysql, real-time-clock

I have a table to record people clocking in and out. I need to find the best way to get a given person's records and add up their hours in a given time period

Here is the table:

tc_timeclock:

```
tc_id | user_id | status | time_stamp
-------------------------------------
1  | 1 | IN  | 2012-11-28 09:00:25
2  | 2 | IN  | 2012-11-28 09:01:25
3  | 3 | IN  | 2012-11-26 09:03:25
4  | 4 | IN  | 2012-11-28 09:21:25
5  | 5 | IN  | 2012-11-28 09:01:12
6  | 6 | IN  | 2012-11-28 09:47:13
7  | 7 | IN  | 2012-11-12 09:00:22
8  | 7 | OUT | 2012-11-12 09:03:28
9  | 5 | OUT | 2012-11-28 09:21:25
10 | 6 | OUT | 2012-11-28 11:47:13
11 | 3 | OUT | 2012-11-26 11:03:25
12 | 2 | OUT | 2012-11-28 11:01:25
13 | 1 | OUT | 2012-11-28 11:27:25
14 | 4 | OUT | 2012-11-28 11:21:25
15 | 4 | IN  | 2012-11-28 12:21:25
16 | 1 | IN  | 2012-11-28 12:27:25
17 | 3 | IN  | 2012-11-26 12:03:25
18 | 6 | IN  | 2012-11-28 12:47:13
19 | 2 | IN  | 2012-11-28 12:01:25
20 | 1 | OUT | 2012-11-28 17:27:25
21 | 4 | OUT | 2012-11-28 17:21:25
22 | 3 | OUT | 2012-11-26 17:03:25
23 | 2 | OUT | 2012-11-28 17:01:25
```

---

I of course can grab all of the rows for a user and it would include all of the IN and OUT status's.
I just don't know the best way to find the time difference (IE how long were they clocked in) between those statuses

The other issue which may be easy enough, is how to find all of this within a certain date range. (ie today, this business week, this pay period.)

Now I am thinking that a portion of this will need to be done in some php, just can't for the life of me figure out the logic.

Comment: Maybe I should ad some sort of key to each entry and make sure that the key matches for specific in/out pairs? This would make finding the pairs pretty much instant.